# How to get direct .xml link from a .php link?

Tags: php, xml, redirect, hyperlink

i have a link ending with .php. If i add this .php link in LiveStreams Addon in XBMC or KODI, i will get some Channels. So the .php link must be redirecting to a .xml link. My question is how can i find out the direct .xml link from the .php link.

Here is the .php link wich i tried to find out: http://on.meshra.com/tamilradio/beta.php?

Is it possible to find out where the php is pointing to?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the 'Answer' I have no reputation post a comment
Are you sending arguments?  The link you provided only has a little html.  I think theres is something missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "redirecting". The PHP script is passing on the XML from whatever its source is, and possibly caching it in the process.

There is no way without the PHP source code to know what the XML source is, short of contacting the website author

Comment: so there is absolutely no way to find out the XML source? I don't have the PHP Source Code.